# ImportError: No module named lxml.etree

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lxml

I'm trying to import premailer in my project, but it keeps failing at the etree import. I installed the 2.7 binary for lxml. The lxml module imports fine, and it's showing the correct path to the library folder if I log the lxml module, but I can't import etree from it. There's an etree.pyd in the lxml folder but python can't seem to see\read it.

I'm on windows7 64bit.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: Is it trying to do `from lxml import etree` or `import lxml.etree as ...` ?

Comment: is it https://github.com/peterbe/premailer?
In https://github.com/peterbe/premailer/blob/master/premailer/premailer.py I see 
`from lxml import etree`

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the library to the GAE .yaml file.

Under libraries add

```
-name: lxml    
 version: latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to using etree without import it  like (lxml.etree() ) I think it function no module
or install it if it a module

Comment: It's a module not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Install `premailer` using

`pip install premailer`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`from lxml import etree`

or

`import lxml.etree` <= This worked for me instead of `lxml.etree()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cygwin's python, or something else?
I wrote a very long answer about all these problems in another post, here:
[ImportError: Permission Denied while using LXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079451/importerror-permission-denied-while-using-lxml/20207574)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i Downloaded and installed the lxml binary from [lfd.uce.edu](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Python 2.7.
It works fine for me.